# Authenticate user through email using Sentinel

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-5.1, cartalyst-sentinel

Is there any way to authenticate a user via email/link/code in Cartalyst Sentinel?

I'm building a simple user registration in Laravel 5.1 which sends a activation email after sign up.
By clicking the link, I'd like to activate and authenticate the user in the same action, but I haven't managed to do that.

The only way seems to be passing the credentials (`Sentinel::($credentials)`), but I just have the `$code` and `$id`, needed for the activation, and it asks for the password (which would be a little insecure the send via email, by the way).

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have or can retrieve the user object (which you need to complete the users activation anyway), then you can use [login()](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#sentinel-login) to login a user without their credentials.

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($id);

Sentinel::login($user);
```

The whole process should look something like this:

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($id);

if ( ! Activation::complete($user, $activationCode))
{
    // ERROR - Invalid or expired activation code.
}

// Login the User
Sentinel::login($user);

// Redirect to where you want to take them
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried it once without success for some reason, but now it works fine. thanks!